# Hierarchized task list?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, tasks, blackberry

The venerable EccoPro offered a great in-place outliner to organize tasks into sub-tasks, and add a Due Date to any item so that they would be also displayed in the Calendar (and in a Palm pilot if the used had one).

It seems like Outlook only supports a single-level task list:

[image]

Is there an add-on to Outlook to do this, or another application than Outlook provided it's also capable of syncing with a BlackBerry?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider a naming scheme that reflects the hierarchy.

Get Life Organized
Get Life Organized - Buy Ecco!
Get Life Organized - Buy Ecco! - Good Move!

Sorting by subject would group related tasks.
You could preserve the order of sublists, if that is important, with minor changes.

An obvious downside would be the additional overhead in changing the name of the a top level task.  Also, task names could be prohibatively long if you require significant nesting, but creative truncation may save you there.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I'd rather let the application handle this :-)

Answer (score 0):

Outlook doesn't support subtasks directly and I don't know of such an addon.

I usually add notes (can be formatted like a Word doc) to structure my tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I'd rather that tasks are listed invidually in the Tasks section so they can be assigned date due's in the Calendar section.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how well this would work with Outlook Tasks, but [**Google Tasks**](http://mail.google.com/mail/help/tasks/) have this along with great keyboard shortcuts if you use [this version](https://mail.google.com/tasks/ig?pli=1). But it also works with Google Calendar, GMail, iGoogle, and [on your smartphone](http://mobile.google.com/). You should be able to pull in the dates from Google Calendar (which would include your task due dates) into Outlook. Possibly even sync with them. There are also some plugins from Chrome and probably Firefox, as well, that make using it even more seamless.

[image]

The screenshot doesn't show any tasks with due dates, but they are supported.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try [Gqueues](http://www.gqueues.com/).

[image: hierarchical tasks in gqueues]

It logs in via your Google account and looks quite promising.

Since it's a web app you could simply view it from your phone anytime you have access to the www.